# Selenium Remotewebdriver Proxy Setting for Safari

Tags: selenium, proxy, selenium-rc, fiddler, remotewebdriver

I am using remote web driver, with fiddlercore as my proxy in c#. What I want to do is use the fiddler proxy to navigate to a url. I can do this with chrome and firefox, but this does not work in safari. Here is my code for firefox.

```
int proxyPort = StartFiddlerProxy(0);
OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
proxy.HttpProxy = "localhost:" + proxyPort; 

var cap = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
cap.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, proxy); 
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetProxyPreferences(proxy);
cap.SetCapability(FirefoxDriver.ProfileCapabilityName, profile)
var webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("localhost:1000/wd/hub"), cap);
```

And when I open firefox, the proxy settings look like this:

[image]

This is my code for safari

```
int proxyPort = StartFiddlerProxy(0);
OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
proxy.HttpProxy = "localhost:" + proxyPort; 

cap = DesiredCapabilities.Safari();
cap.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, proxy);
var webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("localhost:1000/wd/hub"), cap);
```

When I open safari, the proxy settings look like this:
[image]

Note that the settings are not changed at all, even the address and port

Does anyone know how to set the proxy server up correctly?

Comment: Which version of Safari exactly? Safari on Windows is no longer supported. For what it's worth, old versions of Safari used the IE proxy settings, so you could try changing your DesiredCapabilities to point at IE instead.

Comment: I have the latest version of safari. If I change the desiredcapabilities to IE, then selenium opens a IE browser instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of SafariDriver.
It doesn't respect the proxy settings passed through Desired Capabilities.

Firefox, however respects proxy settings through Desired Capabilities.
Safari Driver has acknowledged it as an enhancement.

Comment: Dose safari driver support proxy setting now (Dec-2017) ?